# What is a correct English-to-(Medieval?) Latin translation of the Grail Tablet in "Indiana Jones & the Last Crusade"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

This is my first, and probably only, question on here (I usually hang out on SciFi/Fantasy), so I apologize if I've done it incorrectly or if it's not considered on-topic, but I've wanted to know for years...

In the film *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*, two artifacts that date to the First Crusade (1096-1099CE), or earlier, are inscribed with Latin text that provide clues to the location of the Holy Grail. One, a stone tablet, is fragmented and missing part of the upper portion, while the other, a shield, is complete but you don't see the entire text in the film. At any rate, the relevant text here is meant to be identical.

The text of the tablet reads as follows (including spaces, gaps, punctuation, and missing/partial text):

> ... [qui]squis bibit aquam ruc...
> ... ego dabo ei habebit fontem ...
> ...[r]a se surgentem vitae aeternae fugiu...
> ... domine exercitum rex deorum nostru[m] ...
> ... [b]eati illi qui habitant in aede tua dominu...
> ... [l]audant te in secula saeculorum : sum ...
> ...[+] tu deus es meum refugium : emit ...
> ... [m]itte tuam lucem et veritatem + sint
> ...em + sint hae mihi duces : ducant me ad ...
> ...[a]m sacram montem in loco quem incolis : per
> angustias crescentis lunae : uni viro satis latas
> : ad templum solis omnibus viris satis sanctum ...
> e + ubi gradalis quae continet sanguinem jesu
> christi nostri permanet in aeternum
> tu [deu]s omnibus viris satis sa[nctus] ...

According to Dr. Jones in the movie, a shortened version of the translation is

> "...who drinks the water I shall give him, says the Lord, will have a
> spring inside him welling up for eternal life. Let them bring me to
> your holy mountain in the place where you dwell. Across the desert and
> through the mountains to the Canyon of the Crescent Moon, to the
> temple where the cup that holds the blood of Jesus Christ resides
> forever."

The text on the shield is near identical, with a translation apparently being

> "Who drinks the water I shall give him, says the Lord, will have a
> spring inside him welling up eternal life. O Lord, King of our severe
> gods, blessed are they who dwell in thy temple. O Lord, they praise
> you for all time. You, God, are my refuge : Send forth Thy light and
> Thy truth. These shall be my guide They shall lead me to Thy holy
> mountain in the place where you dwell, across the desert and through
> the mountains, through the canyon of the crescent  moon, narrow enough
> for one man, to the temple of the sun, holy enough for all men, where
> the Grail that holds the blood of Our Jesus Christ dwells forever."

When the propmakers made the props, they took a mix of Psalms, Biblical verse, and their own text, and pretty much word-for-word translated to extremely rough Latin. Prop pictures are included here:

Grail Tablet: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/indianajones/images/b/b7/GrailTablet-TSWA.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110317234456

Knight's shield: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/indianajones/images/5/56/Grailknightshield.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180912191927

I've tried google translate and I don't think it worked too well, plus I have no way of knowing if it's grammatically correct or anything like that. Can someone help me translate this accurately?

Comment: I have to say, they did a much better job than most people inventing Latin text for movies.